# Why doesn't Jooq recognise the type?

Tags: java, postgresql, kotlin, jooq, jooq-codegen

I have an enum SomeType with following structure:

```
enum class SomeType {
    Type1, 
    Type2
}
```

I also have a table with that enum:

```
create type users.some_type as enum ('Type1','Type2');
create table users.some
(
    id   bigint default nextval('users.some_seq'),
    type users.some_type not null,
    primary key (id)
);
```

The enum is generated as:

```
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
enum class SomeType(@get:JvmName("literal") public val literal: String) : EnumType {
    Type1("Type1"),
    Type2("Type2");
    override fun getCatalog(): Catalog? = schema.catalog
    override fun getSchema(): Schema = Users.USERS
    override fun getName(): String = "some_type"
    override fun getLiteral(): String = literal
}
```

However, when I try to write an insert method for that table, it doesn't recognise the enum type:

```
@Transactional
    fun save(some: Some) =
        dslContext.insertInto(
            SOME,SOME.TYPE,
        ).values(some.someType)
```

I'm using Kotlin and Postgres, however I don't think that this problem is Kotlin-specific

Comment: I've fixed it by changing the Some type field to the generated one, but I don't think this is a good solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why doesn't it work

jOOQ can only auto-map `EnumType` enums to a PostgreSQL `enum` type out of the box, not custom enum types. The main reasons include:

- The type name is relevant in many types of queries, where a bind variable has to be cast to the correct type, e.g. `cast(? as users.some_type)` or when using arrays: `cast(? as users.some_type[])`. It just wouldn't work, otherwise, with pgjdbc.
- Some PostgreSQL enum values may be illegal identifiers in Java/kotlin/the JVM, so there needs to be a definition of `EnumType.getLiteral()` for each value, even if in many cases, that's the same value as the Java/kotlin literal for the enum.

As such, you cannot expect your own user defined type to "just work". The fact that it is an `enum` doesn't change that. It's no different from e.g. a `BIGINT` column in PostgreSQL being mapped to something like `MyType`. jOOQ can't just assume any mapping.

### How to get it to work

You can easily attach an [`enumConverter`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-forced-types/codegen-database-forced-types-enum-converter/) (or [any other type of converter](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-forced-types/)) to your generated column. Behind the scenes, jOOQ will still use the generated converter for variable binding, but at least in your user code, you'll only see your own type now.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I really love using JOOQ, it's a great product